# Identify a light emitting component

Tags: components, identification, light

here's a picture of component that is not a LED but emits light, it's a tiny glass light bulb with a resistor and a red plastic case for mounting it.
[image: Unknown Light]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a neon light. Like it says it works at the mains voltage, you can't make it work at 5 V or so. The thing with the neon light is that it needs a higher voltage to ignite, but then the voltage drops, and the series resistor then will control the current, just like for a LED. So you need the resistor, which may have a high value, like 100 kΩ IIRC. Then the current will be in the order of 1 mA.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a [neon lamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_lamp) to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is a neon light bulb and requires AC voltage to operate.  Typically from a wall socket or other high voltage source.  It will also light up if placed in close proximity to high RF energy (typical of a high voltage transformer as in older television sets or radar units where high RF energy is always present).  It will also work close to some microwave systems.  I used to use them attached to the plastic cover of an alligator clip to test RF energy being produced in an aircraft radar system while I was in the Air Force; and used them to verify proper output of the high voltage section of televisions to see if the transformer was producing sufficient RF to power the picture tube.

Reketek

Comment: Does not require AC.